# node.js sequelize transaction using array for queries

Tags: node.js, typescript, sequelize.js

I would like to put the updates on the `clothingModel`  inside a transaction, and if it commits then update `reservationModel`.

This is the code I am trying to rewrite into using `sequelize.transaction`

```
    try {
      data.clothes.forEach(async (clothing) => {
        await this.clothingModel.update(
          { price: clothing.price },
          { where: { id: clothing.clothingId } }
        );
      });
    } catch (e) {
      //throw exception
    }
    //if exception is not thrown
    this.reservationModel.update(
      { dropoffStatus: 'APPROVED' },
      { where: { id: data.reservationId } }
    );
```

But I have struggled to make it conform to the way transactions is used in `sequelize`

```
sequelize.transaction(function (t) {
  return User.create({
    firstName: 'Abraham',
    lastName: 'Lincoln'
  }, {transaction: t}).then(function (user) {
    return user.setShooter({
      firstName: 'John',
      lastName: 'Boothe'
    }, {transaction: t});
  });
}).then(function (result) {
  // Transaction has been committed
  // result is whatever the result of the promise chain returned to the transaction callback 
}).catch(function (err) {
  // Transaction has been rolled back
  // err is whatever rejected the promise chain returned to the transaction callback
});
```

Is it possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be better to turn `transaction` callback into `async` to make it look like sequential code:

```js
try {
  const createdUser = await sequelize.transaction(async t => {
    const user = await User.create({
      firstName: 'Abraham',
      lastName: 'Lincoln'
    }, {transaction: t});
    await user.setShooter({
        firstName: 'John',
        lastName: 'Boothe'
      }, {transaction: t});
    })
  });
  // transaction committed
  .. other code
} catch (err) {
  // transaction rolled back
}
```

Additional example with a cycle:

```
await sequelize.transaction(async t => {
  for(const clothing of data.clothes) {
     await this.clothingModel.update(
       { price: clothing.price },
       { where: { id: clothing.clothingId },
         transaction: t
       }
     );
  }
  // you can move this `update` outside the callback
  // if you wish to execute it out of transaction
  this.reservationModel.update(
    { dropoffStatus: 'APPROVED' },
    { where: { id: data.reservationId },
      transaction: t
    });
});
```

Comment: I think this is more of a suggestion/proposal than an actual answer. I will give you an upvote, but it does not solve my problem

Comment: As I understood you wish to do several changes in the same transaction. If not please clarify a bit in your question what you're trying to achieve

Comment: I would like to use the ``data.clothes`` array for the  queries inside of the transaction

Comment: I added an example with a cycle to my answer